# redirecting user to login page if he's not logged in before sending a message to the admin

Tags: angular, typescript

When a user tries to post a message in the message form, He should be logged in first, if not: when he click the button send message he should be redirected to the login page

I tried using routes guards but they are guarding all the component!

Here's the HTML part

```
    <div class="modal-body">
            <form role="form" #f="ngForm">
                <!-- Validation email -->
                <div class="form-group">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Nom:</label>
                    <input class="form-control required" id="recipient-name" placeholder="Votre nom" name="nom"
                        required [(ngModel)]="nom" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Must be at least 3 characters long, and must only contain letters."
                        type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sender-email" class="control-label">E-mail:</label>
                    <input id="sender-email" type="text"  class="form-control required" data-content="Must be a valid e-mail address (user@gmail.com)"
                        data-trigger="manual" name="email" required [(ngModel)]="email" data-placement="top" placeholder="email@you.com"
                        >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-Phone-Number" class="control-label">Téléphone:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="telephone" [(ngModel)]="telephone" maxlength="60" class="form-control" id="recipient-Phone-Number">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message <span class="text-count">(300) </span>:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text" placeholder="Your message here.." name="text"
                        required [(ngModel)]="text" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p class="help-block pull-left text-danger hide" id="form-error">&nbsp; The form is not valid.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Retour</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" (click)="sendMsg(f)">Envoyer un message!</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
```

and here's the typescript part :

```
 sendMsg(f: NgForm) {
if(this.loginService.loggedIn()){
const msg: Message = f.value;
msg.lu = false;
// msg.nom=this.annonce.nompublieur;
if (this.user != null) {
  msg.id_sender = this.user._id;
  msg.etat = "envoyé";  
}
msg.id_receiver = this.annonce.idclient;
msg.id_annonce = localStorage.getItem('idann');
msg.nom = this.nom;
msg.email = this.email;
msg.text = this.text;
msg.telephone=this.telephone;
//msg.report_reason=this.report_reason;
//msg.email=this.annonce.emailpublieur;
msg.date = this.date.toDateString() + " " + this.date.toTimeString();
console.log(msg.id_annonce);
console.log(msg.id_sender);
console.log(msg.id_receiver);
console.log(msg.nom);
console.log(msg.email);
console.log(msg.telephone);
console.log(msg.text);
console.log(msg);
this.detailsService.Addmessage(msg).subscribe();
console.log("sent");
Promise.resolve(this.detailsAnnonce());
location.reload();}
else{
  alert('login first');
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```

}

in the app-routing module, I used canActivate:[AuthGuard] which takes the user to the login page once he tries to get in the component, what I want is that the user could go into the componenet but once he click the send message button he should be redirected to the login page

Comment: well, in the sendMsg function you should check if user is logged in and act accordingly.

Comment: I edited my sendMsg method, and now I am redirected to the login page when I click the send message button but I can't write nothing now on the login form unless I reload the page

Comment: Well if you cannot write anything on the login form, the issue is in the login form, and we are not seeing that code at all.

Answer (score 0):

remove canActivate:[AuthGuard] from routing module and do a login check in SendMsg() method

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
constructor(private router: Router){
}
sendMsg(f: NgForm) {
let loggedIn : boolean = false;
loggedIn = //make this true if the user is logged in
if(loggedIn)
//your existing logic to post message
}
else{
this.router.navigate(['/login']); //if not logged in then it will be routed to your login page
}
}
```